# How to sum a reference column with a custom ordering

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to sum a column that is from an input table to link to a reference table that a user can select inputs to create a "group."  I think an example is better here:

```
Inputs
Key  Type    Name      Count   lookup_value
1    Fruit   Apple       3     1 - Apple
2    Fruit   Orange      5     2 - Orange
3    Fruit   Pear        6     3 - Pear
4    Veggie  Broccoli    3     4 - Broccoli
5    Veggie  Celery      2     5 - Celery
```

The user puts these inputs in, and from another screen is able to customize a group (each of the selection is from a dropdown,lets call each array of data input_column name such as input_lookup_value for our formulas).  Using the following formula in a cell next to "Total Pieces of Food,"

```
 =sumproduct(--(A1:A3=input_lookup_value),input_count)
```

We will get the correct answer of 14, as below.

```
Group Name:           Food Sally Likes
Total Pieces of Food   14
              Item 
A1           1 - Apple
A2           2 - Orange
A3           3 - Pear
```

However, if the user is to put in just Celery in cell A1, the formula will not work, and the "Total Pieces of Food" will return 0, since the order does not match the Input table order.  Is there another formula or way I can attack this that will return the correct count, and still allow the user to enter the list in any order?

Comment: You could use a "helper" column on your group sheet.  In B1 put `INDEX(input_count,MATCH(A1,input_lookup_value,0))` then sum the helper column.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - and while this would work, I'd like to see if there are any more succinct options out there.  I'd rather not have thousands of "helper" cells floating around.

Comment: I understand, that is the reason I put it in a comment.  My understanding of array formulas are not complete, but I do not know of one that will work.  The reason it works for the first three only, is it cycles one for one.  So it compares A1 to the first on the input list, then it compare A2 to the second.  It does not compare A1 to all input list then A2 to all.  You can compare only A1 to all.  But would need another formula to compare A2 to all.  Again my understanding is far from complete, so I will wait and hope I am wrong.

Comment: Why won't a [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) / [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B) work?

Comment: @Jeeped would that not also require a helper column?

Comment: @ScottCraner - Yes, it would have to be some CSE like `=SUM(SUMIFS(D3:D7, C3:C7, H4:H6))`. ([sample](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jlXFI.png))

Comment: @Jeeped just goes to show that I have more to learn about array formulas. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put what @Jeeped (with his permission) suggested in the comments into an official answer:

[image]

The formula is:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Sheet16!D2:D6, Sheet16!E2:E6, A4:A6))
```

This is an Array Formula, So confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: That worked, I didn't know you could put an array as an input with a matrix formula like that.  Thanks fellas.